# RegionFunction is not working for ComplexPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in version 13.0**

I'm very new to mathematica and I've just begun plotting colorplots for Complex functions. Currently, I'm trying to set the output to be only restricted to the unit disk (|z|<1) and I stumbled upon [RegionFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html). However it seems, [the following sample code under RegionPlot from Mathematica:](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot.html)

```
Table[ComplexPlot[Exp[-z] Sin[3 z], {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> mr, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[z, Abs[z] <= 0.5]], {mr, 0, 2}]
```

does not seem to work. Am I forgetting something or does RegionFunction not apply for Complex Functions?

Comment: It works for me on V 13.0.1  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcUk0.png)  unless you mean something else by _does not seem to work_

Comment: On v12.2.0, Win7-x64, I run `ComplexPlot[Exp[-z] Sin[3 z], {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[z, Abs[z] <= 1]]` to get this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOxz2.png).

Comment: It must be a bug. The `RegionFunction` in `ComplexPlot` does not work in 13.0.1.

Comment: The bug appears to have been introduced in v13.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be a bug. Here is a working around.

```
ComplexPlot[Exp[-z] Sin[3 z], {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{z}, Abs[z]], Mesh -> {{.5}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Automatic, None}]
```

[image]

Another example in document also can not work in 13.0.1 and here we still using `Mesh`.

```
ComplexPlot[(z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1), {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{z, f}, 1 <= Abs[f] <= 2]]
```

```
ComplexPlot[(z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1), {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{z, f}, Abs[f]], Mesh -> {{1, 2}}, 
 MeshShading -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. It seems it is a bug indeed but this workaround does the job!